# How to push local images in React native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have an array of local images I need to push only those images into another array that matches category id. I able to add the images into array but instead giving proper path it's giving number like `445`

that's my array of images

```
 pieImages: [
      require('../assets/images/otherbcateWhite.png'),
      require('../assets/images/non_alcoholicWhite.png'),
      require('../assets/images/alcoholicWhite.png'),
      require('../assets/images/babyFoodWhite.png'),
      require('../assets/images/bakedWhite.png'),
      require('../assets/images/foodWhite.png'),
      require('../assets/images/frozenWhite.png'),
      require('../assets/images/fruitsWhite.png'),
      require('../assets/images/houseHoldWhite.png'),
      require('../assets/images/meatFishWhite.png'),
      require('../assets/images/dairyProductsWhite.png'),
      require('../assets/images/sweetsWhite.png'),
      require('../assets/images/bodyWhite.png'),
      require('../assets/images/hotWhite.png'),
    ]
```

my function to compare id and push it in another array

```
  if (item?.id === itemm?.categoryId) {
              budgetPipeData.Images.pieImages.map((_, index) => {
                if (index === parseInt(itemm.categoryId)) {
                  const img =
                    budgetPipeData.Images.images[parseInt(itemm.categoryId)];
                  console.log(img);
                  images.push(img);
                }
              });
    }
```

and if I use simple string of array for images like

```
pieImages: [
      '../assets/images/otherbcateWhite.png',
    ]
```

it's giving error

```
Could not find image file:///Users/netzwelt/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/344CC058-AD85-4595-9795-25A06A8CD235/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/A8637CD2-7511-4F4F-BBD1-73900FC60914/BoilerPlate.app/../163.png
```

and if I use require inside Image component like

```
<Image source={require(images[index])} />
```

it's give error

```
[Error: TransformError src/components/charts/labels.tsx: src/components/charts/labels.tsx:Invalid call at line 50: require(images[index])]
```

can anyone tell me how can push the images properly?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, that is correct, because `require()` will provide you id of resource at that path and you can directly use it now as `Image` source.

```
<Image source={images[0]} />
```

However, if you want it to use for further use like upload to server, you can store string in an array instead of `require`

```
pieImagesString: [
  '../assets/images/otherbcateWhite.png',
  '../assets/images/non_alcoholicWhite.png'
  ...
]
```

Comment: I tried that but it's not working I updated my question please check